# How to mock filter with repository in constructor?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I created filter which saving abnormal requests and this filter have repository in constructor:

```
@Component
public class LogRequestsFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final LogRepository logRepository;

    @Autowired
    public LogRequestsFilter(LogRepository logRepository) {
        this.logRepository = logRepository;
    }
```

Im trying creating a test like I did earlier in my controller class, but I cant add filter:

```
    @SpyBean
    private LogRepository logRepository;


    @Before
    public void setup(){
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                .addFilters(new LogRequestsFilter(this.logRepository), "/*")
                .build();
    }
```

this gives me error:

```
Inferred type 'T' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; 
should extend 'org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder
```

Comment: You're trying to add the repository as a filter. The repository is not a filter. It's a dependency of the LogRequestsFilter.

Comment: sorry, I wrong paste a code - now is like I did, but error is the same :(

Comment: Which precise line of code causes this compilation error?

Comment: `.addFilters(new LogRequestsFilter(this.logRepository), "/*")`

Comment: It should be addFilter(), not addFilters(). addFilters expects filters, not a filter and a String

Comment: Spring Boot (when using the `@WebMvcTest` or `@SpringBootTest`) should automatically detect your filter. Using `@SpyBean` should be enough to get it constructed and wired. You can simply `@Autowire` the `MockMvc` as that will be setup by Spring Boot.

Answer (score 1):

Thankfully for @M.DEinum and @JB Nizet I created working solution:

```
    @Autowired
    private LogRepository logRepository;


    @Before
    public void setup(){
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
LogRequestsFilter(this.logRepository), "/*")
                .build();
    }
```